# error when applying function to a series object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am using a function for finding minimum value in a column. I get error "int object has no attribute min.I think this might be a syntax error. I know I can directly use do['a'].min() but I want to do this using a function. Can someone please help.

```
  def find_min(columnrow, stat_name):
     if stat_name=='min':
         return columnrow.min()

  val=df['a'].apply(find_min,stat_name='min')
```

Comment: `apply` operates over each row. It makes no _sense_ for you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try `return min(columnrow)`, and change `df['a'].apply(...)` to `df.apply(...)['a']`. (Why not `df['a'].min()`?)

Comment: because there a lot of other stats I want to find and it wont be neat to have all those if else conditions in the main program. I tried your method but it says apply takes at least 2 arguments 1 given.

Comment: @Hue why would writing `.apply(find_min, "min")` be preferable to writing `.min()` ??

Comment: @Hue, actually, with your original definition of `find_min`, this should work: `val=df.apply(find_min,stat_name='min')['a']`. I gotta echo the other commenters here that this approach is unnecessarily roundabout.